# What does "malditas ganas" mean?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

There is a popular song now entitled "Malditas Ganas"

According to google translate, this is "damn win"

That can't be quite right. What is the singer really trying to convey with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it could mean different things depending on the context. `Maldito/a` is one of those swearing words that could stress something as either positive or negative.

The robots from Google (translator) are tranlating "ganas" as 2nd person present simple of "ganar" (to win): tú ganas. But that [*ganas*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=ioDjGq5G9DXX2Xk2BKM9) actually means

> Deseo, apetito, voluntad de algo.

So, it means something like *need for X, craving for X, attitude, willingness or interest to do X, feeling like doing X*, etc.

If the song is [Malditas Ganas](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=2204182) from some "El Komander" guy,

> no se me quitan estas **ganas malditas** de tomar

Means something like "damn **need** to drink". Idem for

> no se me quitan estas **ganas horribles** de llamarte  <sub>this horrible need to call you</sub>

Which is actually not that far from

> no se me quitan estas **ganas benditas** de abrazarte  <sub>this blessed need to hug you</sub>

"Ganas" is either craving, need, want...

> Tengo ganas de ir al cine = Me apetece ir an cine = I want to go to the cinema = I fancy to go to the cinema.

Again, in the song

> me dan ganas de acercarme  <sub>I want to get closer</sub>

so "malditas ganas" is the *damn need* to do X, Y or Z

Answer (score 2):

The expression *tener ganas* means "to be in the mood", so *malditas ganas* (*ganas* is always plural) in that song can mean something like "I hate that I'm in the mood".

Answer (score 1):

It is a little more complex. My first laguage is Spanish from Mexico and it simply means: "These Damm urges of wanting".  But no swear words: "malditas" is not a swear word in Spanish.